# Can't get my Code-Fix to produce the desired result

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

I writing a Code Fix to insert Null Guard checks for a method parameter, whilst preserving the order of the parameters.

```
Public Sub ex(p0 As Example, p1 As Example, p2 As Integer, p3 As Example) ' Comment 1
  If p0 Is Nothing Then Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("p0") 'comment

  Dim a = 0
End Sub
```

Suppose I used the Code Fix to add a null guard for the parameter p3. This should be the following result.

```
Public Sub ex(p0 As Example, p1 As Example, p2 As Integer, p3 As Example) ' Comment 1
  If p0 Is Nothing Then Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("p0") 'comment
  If p3 Is Nothing Then Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("p3")

  Dim a = 0
End Sub
```

but what I actually get is

```
Public Sub ex(p0 As Example, p1 As Example, p2 As Integer, p3 As Example) ' Comment 1
  If p0 Is Nothing Then Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("p0") If p3 Is Nothing Then Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("p3")         'comment

    Dim a = 0
End Sub
```

or

```
Public Sub ex(p0 As Example, p1 As Example, p2 As Integer, p3 As Example) ' Comment 1
  If p0 Is Nothing Then Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("p0")
  If p3 Is Nothing Then Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("p3")         'comment

    Dim a = 0
End Sub
```

The code used can be found on GitHub ([repo](https://github.com/AdamSpeight2008/NullParameterCheckRefactoring/tree/vb-support_order_preserving))
*The algorithm used is likely rubbish but it works. *

No matter what I've tried I can't seem to get the correct result.

- All the guards end up on the same line
- All the guards end up on separate line but comment is deleted / moved to end of last guard.

Can any one see what I've missed to produce the desired result?

---

Additional

```
  Dim ifStatements = method.Statements.Where(Function(s) (TypeOf s Is MultiLineIfBlockSyntax)
                     OrElse (TypeOf s Is SingleLineIfStatementSyntax))
  Dim ExistingGuards = ifStatements.Where(Function(s)
    If TypeOf s Is SingleLineIfStatementSyntax Then
      Dim singleIF = DirectCast(s, SingleLineIfStatementSyntax)
      Dim isExpr = TryCast(singleIF.Condition, BinaryExpressionSyntax)
      Return CheckIfCondition(isExpr)
    ElseIf TypeOf s Is MultiLineIfBlockSyntax Then
      Dim multiIF = DirectCast(s, MultiLineIfBlockSyntax)
      Dim isExpr = TryCast(multiIF.IfStatement.Condition, BinaryExpressionSyntax)
      Return CheckIfCondition(isExpr)
    Else
      Return False
    End If
  End Function).ToList()
```

I would expect the trivia to be preserved for each statement, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

Did you try the formatter annotation?

```
         replacement = ifStatement.WithStatement(
                 SyntaxFactory.Block(ifStatement.Statement)
                    .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation));
```

Is that how you fixed them all being on the same line?

The comment needs to be trailing trivia on the last token on the line - the parentheses

Comment: yep. See addition info.

Comment: When I examine the result of the LINQ query I can find .Node.Green and it has the comment trivia.